# What is the best way to edit WP plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to ask what is the best way to edit somebody else's plugin in a way if they do the updates and I apply them it won't wipe out my additions?

I was wondering if creating php file inside the plugin folder and adding the plugins functions would be ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing WordPress plugins is not similar to WordPress themes, i.e. creating a child plugin.

Best way to do is following this tips: https://iandunn.name/the-right-way-to-customize-a-wordpress-plugin/

You can create a fork of the plugin or use custom hooks to edit the plugin.

Comment: is there a tutorial on how to do it?